# Incorrect decryption RSA pycryptodome

Tags: python, encryption, rsa, pycryptodome

I try to implement RSA in Python with pycryptodome, the encrypt Works fine but the decrypt function no, my code is the following:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
from Crypto.Signature import pss
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256

class RSA_OBJECT:


           def create_KeyPair(self):

    self.key = RSA.generate(self.KEY_LENGTH)


def save_PrivateKey(self, file, password):

    key_cifrada = self.key.export_key(passphrase=password, pkcs=8,protection="scryptAndAES128-CBC")
    file_out = open(file, "wb")
    file_out.write(key_cifrada)
    file_out.close()


def load_PrivateKey(self, file, password):
           key_cifrada = open(file, "rb").read()
    self.private_key = RSA.import_key(key_cifrada, passphrase=password)


def save_PublicKey(self, file):
          key_pub = self.key.publickey().export_key()
    file_out = open(file, "wb")
    file_out.write(key_pub)
    file_out.close()

def load_PublicKey(self, file):

    key_publica = open(file, "rb").read()
    self.public_key = RSA.import_key(key_publica)
```

I don't know why, because I think that the code is correct, anyone can help me?

Comment: Done, i upload cifrar

Comment: i upload all the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem you generate two different keys;

```
self.public_key = RSA.generate(self.KEY_LENGTH)
self.private_key = RSA.generate(self.KEY_LENGTH)
```

you should;

```
key = RSA.generate(self.KEY_LENGTH)
```

and

```
private_key = key.export_key()
file_out = open("private.pem", "wb")
file_out.write(private_key)

public_key = key.publickey().export_key()
file_out = open("receiver.pem", "wb")
file_out.write(public_key)
```

See [here](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/examples.html) in more details;

---

**Note:** note that key object has two functionality due to public keys encryption. You can write a private key into a file and public key into another. In this way, you can distribute the key. See [RSAKey](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/public_key/rsa.html#Crypto.PublicKey.RSA.RsaKey).

Comment: I dont know exactly how to change my code with this information

Comment: in the create_KeyPair write to file. Then load from the file.

Comment: Thaks for all, now Works perfectly

Comment: I think that the important code is the code that i edit

Comment: @Doe put the new part at the end of your question with a title, that is better. Let the people see the original and the solution.